# Parboiled and Cglib dependency conflict

Tags: maven, cglib, parboiled

I'm working on a program that uses cglib, included as part of a large package of dependencies (version 2.1_3), and have written a new feature using parboiled processor to do some markdown to html conversion.

The problem arises with a dependency conflict.
If I do nothing, all of my tests for the parboiled feature fail, with messages along the lines of:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org/parboiled/transform/ParserClassNode
```

And if I include the following exclusion

```
<exclusion>
     <groupId>asm</groupId>
     <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

where my big dependency is declared, all of the parboiled tests will pass, but most of the others will fail, with messages like

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer
```

I am using pegdown 1.4.1

Any suggestions? Browsing the internet seems to suggest using a new version of asm (4.0 or later, the one in my project at the moment is 1.5.3) may help, but trying to exclude the asm I have and import the later one didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that cglib is hard to migrate. This is because:

- newer cglib versions are not compatible to their earlier versions
- newer [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org) versions are not compatible to their earlier versions (cglib is built on top of asm)

The [FAQ to ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html#Q15) therefore recommends:

> **15** How to resolve conflicts between different ASM API versions available in a global classpath or within the same ClassLoader?
>
> Tools and frameworks that are using ASM for bytecode processing (e.g.
>   Hibernate, CGLIB, AspectWerkz) should repackage ASM code within their
>   own name space. This can be automated with [Jar Jar Links](http://tonicsystems.com/products/jarjar/) tool.

I recommend you to do the same with cglib. Move the entire dependency into a new package (create a independent name space) and only use this dependency. It is ugly, but it is the only solution. Other projects like [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cglib/package-summary.html) or Hibernate deal with cglib in the same manner.